# Audit logout - high CPU Utilization

Tags: sql-server, performance, cpu, audit, sql-server-profiler

Why is Audit Logout taking very high CPU(13K reading on profiler). At this period the whole servers max out on CPU(100%) for like 5 minutes. I need to understand why this is with Audit Logout

Answer (score 1):

According to the [BOL article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175827.aspx) on that event, the CPU is the aggregate CPU used for that connection over its lifetime. So the event itself isn't consuming any CPU, but rather is reporting all of the CPU that's been used by that session since connecting.